# What is the difference between "diverse" and "versatile"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, context

I have this sentence:

> John is a **(versatile/diverse)** football player, he can play multiple positions on the pitch.

In this context, which word should I use?

The meaning of ***diverse*** is:

> showing a great deal of variety; very different.

And, the meaning of ***versatile*** is:

> able to adapt or be adapted to many different functions or activities.

They both mean that somebody is good at doing a variety of different tasks.

For this context, which word *(diverse or versatile)* should I choose and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Diverse** refers to people, subjects, or ideas. **Versatile** refers to what a person, subject, or idea can *do*.

> The ideas the team put forth were very **diverse**.

versus

> A multi-tool is **versatile** since it can be used for many different purposes.

For John, I would say he is a very **versatile** player, able to be counted on in many different positions.